# Where do I find files specific to a user?

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, erlang

I've been having a problem connecting to my rabbitmq server when I start it on my local machine. Apparently the erlang cookie of the server, running on my local machine, does not match the cookie on my local machine. I found an old post on the internet explaining that such a problem when running on a local machine can be caused by the fact that I'm not running rabbitmq as a rabbitmq user which is  created for you by the installer. So I did just that and started rabbitmq as rabbitmq user, with the following command.

```
sudo -H -u rabbitmq bash /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server
```

How does it really work? Since I don't have a dedicated folder for the user rabbitmq I want to understand where erlang cookie can be saved for the mentioned user, so that it does not match the cookie inside MY home folder (it IS there). Also I would like to know how the command --set-home would work in the context of the given command given such user does not (to my understanding) have a home directory.

Comment: I don't know anything about rabbitmq, but it sounds like you want to know what the user's home directory is set to when you execute the command: if so, you can use `sudo -H -u rabbitmq sh -c 'echo $HOME'` (it's important to use single quotes here). OTOH it's possible that rabbitmq is configured to save the cookie somewhere other than its user's `$HOME`

Comment: That's actually the command I was looking for, thanks! I didn't know you could set a home directory for a user inside the /var/lib.

Answer (score 1):

The RabbitMQ installer creates the `rabbitmq` user and sets the home directory to `/var/lib/rabbitmq`. You can discover this by looking for the `rabbitmq` user in `/etc/passwd`.

> Apparently the erlang cookie of the server, running on my local machine, does not match the cookie on my local machine.

How do you know this? Did you run a command and see an error? This is important information.

The way RabbitMQ is intended to be used when installed via a package is to be started by `init` (`systemd`) as the `rabbitmq` user. Then, when you need to run `rabbitmqctl`, you do so as `root` and the command switches to the `rabbitmq` user, ensuring that the correct cookie is used.

You may be able to copy the `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` file to your home directory and run `rabbbitmqctl` as your own user.

---

<sub>**NOTE:** the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.</sub>

Comment: I know that the cookie does not match since I looked at the logs that the rabbitmq provides when I try to login with rabbitmqctl. I can't provide the exact error message at the moment, but I searched for that error message and found numerous posts of people telling it's probably caused by the cookie mismatch. So I looked how to rectify that, and eventually came up with an idea to run rabbitmq as the rabbitmq user, which helped. That's how I reached a conclusion that cookie does indeed mismatch.